# MySQL - PDO bindParam

Tags: mysql, pdo

`$request_id_col` and `$request_id` are strings. However, the request_id_col type in the table is an integer.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('  SELECT r.qty, d.name
                          FROM requested_devices r
                          JOIN devices d ON r.device_id = d.id
                          WHERE r.:request_id_col = :request_id
                          ORDER BY r.id');

$stmt->bindParam(':request_id_col', $request_id_col);
$stmt->bindParam(':request_id', $request_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

I'm receiving error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''sample_id' = '101' ORDER BY r.id' at line 4'
```

How do I make a query by correctly using bindParam's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind table or column names. Only values.

Comment: May you provide a proper way to do the query I'm trying to make?

Comment: Don't try to make it dynamic. If you want a different column in your query then use a different query.

Comment: I can make different queries for each $request_id_col. However, $request_id will be based off the row_id a user is editing, and there are hundreds. It won't be practical for me to make different queries for each one.